# The network address entered is invalid - Windows 7

Tags: dns, windows-7

I am trying to change the DNS server IP on my Windows 7 and I see this weird error.

> The network address entered is invalid

It comes up for all types of IP addresses. Any idea why Windows thinks it is an invalid IP address for a DNS server.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Oops. That was a silly error. If you notice(window top), I was trying to edit the IPv6 network address by mistake. I was able to add that address in IPv4 window.

What happened to Microsoft's super friendly error messages?, something like

> you dumbo, you entered a IPv4 address for IPv6. IPv6 addresses look
>   complex, for example,
>
> 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334

Comment: Yay free points for you -- some other dumbo might stumble on this :)  PS Microsoft was never backward compatible... heheheh..